# Parallel processing in app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

For each request my app gets, it sends a lot of URL fetch requests for many APIs,
And I want send and process their response in parallel.

It's not heavy in computation, just in the time it takes to wait for the external API's response.

What is the best why to use make paralleled it?
thread? task queue?

Or even, I thought about sending HTTP from the main servlet to other servlets in my app.

Comment: In my opinion just use standard threading, unless its really 100s of thousands of connections which may need a better approach of utilising multiple processors in parallel e.g mpi in C ? But I believe that would be an overkill , just stick to standard threads. Java concurrency is pretty good

Comment: Appengine front end requests do not allow the creation of threads.

Comment: Please search stackoverflow before posting duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373469/multithreading-with-appengine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options

Consider using async urlfetch, have a read of this article.  http://ikaisays.com/2010/06/29/using-asynchronous-urlfetch-on-java-app-engine/

If you have a big number of URLS (you haven't quantified how many you have) consider using a task queue, you have a 10min request time.

Alternately use a pull queue submit URL's to be processed and a backend that processes the requests and then you can use threads in a backend instance.

Answer (score 0):

Like Tim said, asych urlfetch is the easiest and best option.

If you're worried about the time it takes for the request to GAE to finish, you could kick off a deferred task in a task queue and return from the request right away, and have that 10 minutes in the task queue task.